# Running multiple python files on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have 3 files:

1. **webapp.py** => simple flask app that with every GET requests reads stock.txt and shows it content
2. **scrapper.py** => simple bs4 scrapper that scraps a site every 5 minutes and saves its stock to a file stock.txt
3. **stock.txt** => stores the stock from scrapper.ppy

I have no problem running it on my local pc but i dont know how to deploy it to heroku

I cant find an simple answer on heroku docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you'll find a lot of problems if you are not familiar with Heroku in the first place.

In Heroku you have to build your `Procfile` and with this configure your webapp, clock and jobs.

Example `Procfile` for a web application:

```ini
web: gunicorn webapp:app
```

Example `Procfile` for a clock (scheduled job):

```ini
clock: python scrapper.py
```

And with the last one you have some serious problem because Heroku have a virtual instance of you code so modifications to your repository files will not be persisted. Maybe think of using a Database.

PS: You only need one `Procfile` containing the deployment information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer is there any other deployment option except vps that i could have persistent state of files ?

Comment: You could try **[PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)**